# How to install 14.10 from demo?

Tags: software-installation, 14.10

I have an Ubuntu 14.10 live disk. I booted it from the CD on my hp 2000 64 bit laptop. The demo works fine but when I try to download the full version it just restarts and runs the demo version again.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "demo" and "download the full version"?If you mean by "demo" the "Try Ubuntu without installing", you can start the installation from within there. (Desktop icon) This should even work without any downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've already installed Ubuntu to your laptop's HD, or if it's rebooting before it gets that far...

Did you change the BIOS's boot order to boot from the USB/CD first? If it has already installed Ubuntu,  maybe just unplugging the USB / ejecting the CD or changing the boot order back would work & let the HD boot.

After reading updated info, *maybe* it has installed Ubuntu already, but isn't booting correctly, could try using https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair from inside the live/cd Ubuntu...

Comment: uh.. i do not know what that means. it is not from a usb, it is from a disk. when i boot from the disk I get the demo version. On the demo version, ubuntu works and everything but the disk is constantly running. when I choose install ubuntu 14.10, and select install ubuntu inside windows 7 then continue it ejects the disk it takes me to the windows boot manager. then i run ubuntu from there, it reloads then says "initramfs) unable to find a medium containing a live file system." What do I do?

Comment: Oops, I'll replace "usb" with "cd", same idea... that *"install ubuntu inside windows 7"* sounds kind of like WUBI, that method's not recommended anymore, I'm not sure what to do about that...

Comment: then what should i do? i bought this disk from ebay for not much. Obviously from my descriptions i am not a super techy person. I want ubuntu because my computer is getting slower. I tried downloading it several ways but they never work,and when I read several articles about how to install it they just go over my head. Maybe ubuntu has made downloading it hard to keep the noobs out. But what if the noobs want in? It is wubi by the way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're moving away from WUBI because it doesn't work with Windows 8, but it might still be ok with older windows'. Maybe there's a "install beside" or "install alongside" or "dual boot" option in the installer that would work? May need to make some free space on the drive first, maybe shrink the windows or other partition... If the guides & Ubuntu help like https://help.ubuntu.com/ or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommunityHelpWiki don't help, I can't add much